# Wix react-native-natifications FCM setup for remote is incomplete?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, wix, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to use react-native-notifications module - https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications for Android remote push notifications.

However it seems their setup procedure is incomplete for remote. They don't tell us how to add the `c2dm` or `GcmReceiver` etc in AndroidManifest.xml - I created an issue topic 9 days ago but I got no support - https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/170

Does anyone have any ideas on how to setup react-native-notifications for Android?

In this topic here - https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/173#issuecomment-357000300 - he recommends to use this branch - https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/react-native-notifications/tree/android-overhaul

However I don't know how to set it up.